# maximum number of testers on a appcenter app for iOS and android

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I'm using appcenter to build and distribute to my testers my app.

what is the number of maximum invites I can send for iOS and android?

Is this like iOS internal testers = 25 and external testers = 1000? what is appcenter using to distribute the apps?